# How should I structure a UINavigationController with an atypical header?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app which uses a large custom header (see pic). There are two ways I can think of structuring this:

1. Subclass `UINavigationController` and add the header there. Unfortunately, I can't edit topLayoutGuide or layOutSubviews, so child layout is a problem.
2. Just hide the `navigationBar` and put the custom header view in each child.

Is there any way to manage child layout in the case of #1? I also use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` to animate the views. Would that make one solution preferable?

[image]